# How to access a PHP object property outside of a class?

Tags: php, variables, object, scope

For example, let's say I have the file "other.php" that contains this code

```
class Building
{
    public $name;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->$name = $name;
    }
}

$bd = new Building("Name");
echo $bd->$name;
```

This returns errors like this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in (...)
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in (...)
```

And I wish for an output like

```
Name
```

How do I access PHP object properties in such a fashion? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the second `$`. You access it with `$bd->name;`. Same goes for inside the class. Put `$this->name` instead of `$this->$name` in there.

Generally, just **don't** put a `$` after the `->` operator.

Look at the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for reference.

Comment: Doing that seems to remove the error but gives me no output. [This is my specific code.](https://gist.github.com/Elsealabs/16c44d935030c5a0bc0a)

Comment: Same goes for inside the class. You access it with `$this->$name`, while it should actually be `$this->name`.

Comment: When I include that file in my index.php using `<?php include("buildings.php"); ?>`  and then later on in my index.php write `<?php echo $buildings_HSB->name; ?>` it gives errors. `Notice: Undefined variable: buildings_HSB in (...)` and `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in (...)`

Comment: This is [my updated class file.](https://gist.github.com/Elsealabs/16c44d935030c5a0bc0a)

Comment: And in another HTML file I am doing `<?php include("buildings.php"); ?>` and then `<?php echo $buildings_HSB->name; ?>` and am receiving the errors listed above.

Comment: Your variable is called `$building_HSB`, you've put an additional _s_ in there.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the `$` sign infront of name.

It should be like `echo $bd->name;`..

Answer (score 1):

First fix your class code:

```
function __construct($name)
{
    $this->$name = $name;
}
```

Should be this:

```
function __construct($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

Which will allow you to access it like this:

```
$bd = new Building("Name");
echo $bd->name;
```

---

Addressing your issue in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926155/how-to-access-a-php-object-property-outside-of-a-class/24926257#comment38731632_24926185)

You get that error because you havent instantiated that variable.

You should do this:

```
$buildings_HSB = new Building("Name");
echo $buildings_HSB->name;
```